# state value (on Test2.js) not changing in react-native for the given below code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

First thing is that in Test1.js when i uses Test2.js two time.In the first one I passes the data="First" and in second one I passes data="Second". But when the screen render and when I press the Button First It show "First" on the screen but when I press button second,it do'nt render "Second" on screen.
As I found that the value of state in the Test2.js is not changing.
Can You explain me why the value of state is not changing in the Test2.js

And can anyone tell how to fix this.And more thing if  I uses  component instead of this.A() and this.B() it works fine but as below method not works.

Here is the code..

**Test1.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements'
import Test2 from './Test2';
var a = "First"
var b = "second"
export default class Test1 extends Component {

    state={
        activeA:true,
        activeB:false
    }
    A = ()=>{
        return( <Test2 data={a}/>)
    }
    B = () =>{
        return(<Test2 data={b}/>)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex:1,justifyContent:'center',padding:20}}>
               <Button buttonStyle={{ marginBottom: 10}} title="First" onPress={()=>{this.setState({activeA:true,activeB:false})}}/>
               <Button  buttonStyle={{ marginBottom: 10}} title="Second" onPress={()=>{this.setState({activeA:false,activeB:true,})}}/>

               {this.state.activeA?this.A():this.B()}

            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**Test2.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Test2 extends Component {
      state={
        data:this.props.data
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text syle = {{fontSize:20,}}> {this.state.data} </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the `state` from `Test2`. it doesn't need any state, just render the props directly

Comment: @azium actually It's my requirement to use the value as a state. since the above code I just for understanding purpose, in actual it my requirement to put that value as a state as I have to do a lot of on the this.props.data so I have to put that value in the state.

Comment: why is your requirement to write bad code?

Comment: i have to set that props data to set an array max value and then render it on screen that value whenever the props value change.

Answer (score 0):

Do not transfer to the `status` value, but render directly.

**Test2.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Test2 extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { data } = props
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text syle = {{fontSize:20,}}> {this.props.data} </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
Test2.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: actually It's my requirement to use the value as a state. since the above code I just for understanding purpose, in actual it my requirement to put that value as a state as I have to do a lot of on the this.props.data so I have to put that value in the state.

Comment: I updated the answer in line with your additional comments.